# RabbitMQ server is not starting after installation in Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows, windows-7, erlang, rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ in my Windows 7 machine but it's not getting started and throws following error:

> Unable to connect to epmd on : address (cannot connect to host/port)

I have installed RabbitMQ 3.5.4 and Erlang 18.0.

I used `netstat -an` and I was able to see port 4369 is in listening mode, but I don't see 5672, 5671 ports in listening mode, is that the problem? if so how to resolve it?

I tried to reinstall both Erlang and RabbitMQ, but no luck.

I thought latest version of RabbitMQ is not supported in Windows 7, so downgraded to RabbitMQ 3.1.3. but no luck.

I have even added hostname in Windows hosts file, no luck.

My Windows firewall is already turned off, so wont be blocking any port.

From "Services" Window, I see RabbitMQ service is not started. even if I manually start it, it again goes back to stopped state.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Windows Firewall to make sure it's allowing all the proper ports through?

According to [the RabbitMQ docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html):

```
Port Access

Firewalls and other security tools may prevent RabbitMQ from binding to a port. When that happens, RabbitMQ will fail to start. Make sure the following ports can be opened:

4369 (epmd), 25672 (Erlang distribution)
5672, 5671 (AMQP 0-9-1 without and with TLS)
15672 (if management plugin is enabled)
61613, 61614 (if STOMP is enabled)
1883, 8883 (if MQTT is enabled)

It is possible to configure RabbitMQ to use different ports.
```

I would turn of Windows Firewall and see if it runs. If it runs with Firewall off, then you will need to open these ports in the Firewall

Answer (score 1):

Have you already follow this guide to troubleshoot your problem?

https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting.html

Taking from above link:

> If the (windows) service fails to start, make sure the service has been installed.
>     On starting the service, if the service output reads "The process terminated unexpectedly" instead, then the service did not start
>    correctly. Check that the environment variables are set correctly. The
>    logfiles in RABBITMQ_BASE may also contain useful diagnostic
>    information.
>    If RABBITMQ_BASE path contains non-ASCII characters, RabbitMQ service may fail to start with the error "RabbitMQ: Erlang machine
>    stopped instantly (distribution name conflict?)". If this is the case,
>    override RABBITMQ_BASE to point to a directory that only has ASCII
>    characters and re-install the service (restarting will not be
>    sufficient).

Comment: i  expiriensed all kinds of issues  with  user profile named with  cyrillic  symbols. resolved by  moving  all rabbitmq stuff  from profile to short latin named dir  and  manually  patched the registry to  update the  paths.